# Is there a nodivergence Moser's Harnack Inequality

Tags: inequality, partial-differential-equations

[image]

If we change the operator $Lu = div(a_{i,j}Du)$ where $A_{i,j}$ is a simmetric matrix by the fully nonlinar elliptic operator

$$
F(x,D^2u)
$$

as in [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oaS5v.png). The result istill holds?

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oaS5v.png) L. Caffarelli, X. Cabré, Fully Nonlinear Elliptic Equations, Amer. Math. Soc., Providence, RI, 1995

Comment: The Harnack inequality for uniformly elliptic equations in non-divergence form is called the Krylov-Safonov Harnack inequality